# Hide older content in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

HTML code is as follows -

```
<div id="myDiv" style="max-height:500px; overflow-y:auto;margin-top: 15px" >
    <div id="myInnerDiv" style="display:none;border:1px solid black;">
        <span class='myLine' >data1</span>
        <span class='myLine' >data2</span>
        <span class='myLine' >data3</span>
        <span class='myLine' >data4</span>
        <span class='myLine' >data5</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

visibility of `myInnerDiv` is controller depending on the content. Now lines with class `myLine` are dynamically added. As you can notice `overflow-y:auto` is provided if content exceeds `max-height:500px` we will see scroll bar. What I want it to show latest 5 lines only. So if we add

```
<span class='myLine' >data5</span>
```

then

```
<span class='myLine' >data1</span>
```

should be removed or hidden. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('.myLine').length() > 5 ) {

  $('.myLine').first().remove();

}
```

something like that.  or you could add a new class to the .first() and have it hidden.

Comment: Interesting. Will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this. With this solution you don't lose your content from "older" lines.

and you should probably use `div` instead of `span` since span has `display: inline-block` as standard and therefore won't give you a new line

**//EDIT**
first gets hidden and new one gets appended

```js
$('.addLine').click(function(){
  $('#myInnerDiv').append('<div class="myLine">test</div>');
  
  if($('#myInnerDiv').find('.myLine').length > 5) {
     
      $('#myInnerDiv').find('.myLine').not('.hidden').first().addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="max-height:500px; overflow-y:auto;margin-top: 15px" >
    <div id="myInnerDiv" style="display:block;border:1px solid black;">
        <div class='myLine' >data1</div>
        <div class='myLine' >data2</div>
        <div class='myLine' >data3</div>
        <div class='myLine' >data4</div>
        <div class='myLine' >data5</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="addLine">add Line </div>
```

Comment: Good approach. I want to append at the bottom. So I guess I would have to change you code correspondingly to appen at bottom and  make first hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.myLine').length() > 5 ) {

  $('.myLine').first().replaceWith(yourData);

}
```

Comment: Good approach but I would have to dynamically create `yourData`.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically scroll the div (myDiv) to bottom.

So that last values will automatically be visible.

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var objDiv = $('$myDiv');
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

        });
        <script>
```